# How to store a drawn feature in OpenLayers?

Tags: geojson, openlayers

I have found a draw tool in OpenLayers-3 which allows us to draw on a map (see http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.0/examples/draw-features.html). Is there an API in openlayers to store the drawn feature in geojson format?

Comment: Where do you want to store it? Local storage in the browser? On the server using WFS-T?

Comment: @bartvde i just want to get the drawn feature in geojson format and store it in a text file on the server (say)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ol.format.GeoJSON to write out your feature as GeoJSON, and then use any AJAX / XHR library to get it back to your server.

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.format.GeoJSON.html#writeFeature

See also this example which uses EsriJSON but the concepts are the same:

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/examples/vector-esri-edit.html

Comment: but the problem is how do I store a drawn "feature" into a variable? Please see the link I have posted in the question above. It just draws the feature on the map and doesn't store it anywhere.

Comment: please check the vector-esri-edit example it should tell you all you need

Comment: I am right now on openlayers 3.4.0, which doesn't seem to have this

Comment: Then check out 3.5.0. Or just view the online example for the code.

Answer (score 4):

Further to the answer above, this is how I'm grabbing the draw features before storing them in an indexed db for offline storage:

```
// declare vars to populate later
var routetitle, routeDescription, routeFeatures, 
routeScreenshot, routePNG, tags;



// THIS IS THE IMPORTANT BIT
var allFeatures = drawLayer.getSource().getFeatures();
var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
var routeFeatures = format.writeFeatures(allFeatures);
```

If you then console log(routeFeatures it should give you a JSON Feature Collection